# How to v-for without creating a DOM entry?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have data I would like to present in a CSS Grid. The end result should be

```
<div>hello 1</div><div>hello 2</div>
<div>bonjour 1</div><div>bonjour 2</div>
```

I envision the creation of the grid through a `v-for`, iterating over data I receive from somewhere (in the example below, it is represented by the Array `['hello', 'bonjour']`).
My problem is that the iteration creates an extra `<div>` enclosing the two elements I am interested in:

```
<div v-for="for word in ['hello', 'bonjour']">
<div>{{word}} 1</div><div>{{word}} 2</div>
</div>
```

The result is

```
<div><div>hello 1</div><div>hello 2</div></div>
<div><div>bonjour 1</div><div>bonjour 2</div></div>
```

**Is there a way to iterate over an iterator without creating an extra element?**

In pseudocode this would be something like

```
<this-element-is-not-added-to-the-DOM-but-just-manages-the-word-variable v-for="for word in ['hello', 'bonjour']">
<div>{{word}} 1</div><div>{{word}} 2</div>
</this-element-is-not-added-to-the-DOM-but-just-manages-the-word-variable>
```

Comment: Please [search thoroughly](/search?q=%5Bvue.js%5D+v-for+without+element) before posting. More about searching [here](/help/searching).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I will be honest and say that I did not search. Why? because I use Vue for years and have read the docs back and forth so I had the "how come nobody had that problem?" eureka moment and really was arrogant enough to imagine that I would be the first :)

Comment: LOL :-D I've **never** done something like that... :;-)

Answer (score 5):

You can wrap in a `template`:

```js
new Vue({ el: "#app" });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <template v-for="word in ['hello', 'bonjour']">
    <div>{{word}} 1</div><div>{{word}} 2</div>
  </template>
</div>
```